# What is sdkpackagename on Leadbolt?

Tags: android, permissions, ads, leadbolt

I am trying to integrate Leadbolt to my android application..

Its integration guide says.

```
<service android:name="com.<sdkpackagename>.ReEngagementService"></service>
<service android:name="com.<sdkpackagename>.AdBootReceiverService"></service> 
<receiver android:name="com.<sdkpackagename>.ReEngagement" /> 
<receiver android:name="< YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME >.BootReceiver">
```

to be integrated on manifest. What is it meant by sdkpackagename?

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the package of the leadbolt library. So this will probably be something like: com.Leadbolt

Answer (score 0):

go to download sdk in ur leadblot publisher account below u will find a package name starting with  com.

Answer (score 0):

The Leadbolt SDK package name is a hash-of-some-kind generated individually for each developer account.

When you apply to download their SDK, a ZIP file will be generated containing the main Leadbolt library named like "taedgzcbsbf.jar", in which the Leadbolt API classes will have package names like: "com.taedgzcbsbf.*". So, to use the library on an app project, the developer will be importing something like "com.taedgzcbsbf.AdController".

The mentioned ZIP file also contains some other libraries that intend to help the integration of Leadbolt ads on third party APIs or mediators such as AdMob, Flurry, PhoneGap, etc.

PS: The hash string I used as example of package name is a resemble of, but not intended to be an actual generated Leadbolt hash. I have mixed some letters just to illustrate the answer.